# Finding speech in a WAV file

Tags: c#, wav, naudio

I'm trying to write a c# program with NAudio that helps me identify when speech begins and ends and how long the speech has gone on for.

So far i've tried to measure the amplitude of the samples but i'm not sure this is the correct approach to take.

I've heard about FFT's but i'm not sure this is the correct method either.

I don't mind doing the research myself but i'm just looking for some guidance in the direction to take.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  While you have the right idea in asking for help, SO is unfortunately not the place to ask this type of question.  SO is designed to help users with their code directly, not (usually) for concepts such as this.  You will have much better luck on one of the other StackExchange sites.  (Unfortunately again, I'm not sure which one would suit your needs most, otherwise I would recommend one!)

Comment: May I recommend the signal processing stack? http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks alot, i'll check i out, as it stands i've found another method to try out so i'm testing that at the moment.